# Django Unique Constraint for Three fields Not working

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have the following model.

```
class ModelAnswer(BaseModel):
    questions = models.ForeignKey(
        to=ModelQuestions,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    answer = models.TextField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.questions} - by {self.user}'

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['created_at','user', 'questions' ], name='unique questions per user')
        ]
```

plan is to have one  answer  per  question by user per day ie on next day  new answer can be added for new question but only once. I tried adding unique constraint but it does not work

My question model is as

```
class ModelQuestions(BaseModel):
    MODEL_CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
        ('Circumstances', 'Circumstances'),
        ('Thoughts', 'Thoughts'),
        ('Feelings', 'Feelings'),
        ('Action', 'Action'),
        ('Result', 'Result'))
    model_subcategory = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=MODEL_CATEGORY_CHOICES)
    questions = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.model_subcategory
```

How do I allow the unique answers to questions by users each day?
Although I tried filtering method with exists() soln but I want to implement with unique constraint.

Comment: Is `created_at` a date field or date time field? Did you apply the migrations after adding your unique constraints?

Comment: yes i did all created_at is at basemodel class

Comment: created_at is date_time field

Answer (score 0):

you can do this like this code

```
class ModelAnswer(BaseModel):
    questions = models.ForeignKey(
    to=ModelQuestions,
    on_delete=models.CASCADE
)
    answer = models.TextField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Meta:
    unique_together = ('created_at', 'user', 'questions', {'message': 
              'created_at, user, and questions must be unique together'})
```